# How to show filename when AWK found matches?

Tags: linux, awk

I have a small script that searches all txt files for a string and outputs the matches. Is there a way to show the filename above the match but only when a match was found? Currently I am using this:

```
find . -iname "*.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 awk -v RS='' 'tolower($0) ~ /cool/;'
```

I tried to add FILENAME to the end of the script but now it only displays the filename and not the matches:

```
find . -iname "*.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 awk -v RS='' 'tolower($0) ~ /cool/{print FILENAME};'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you're not printing the line, change to

```
   ... {print $0, FILENAME} ...
```

`print` without arguments means `print $0`, and default statement is `{print}` when missing as in your first script.

Answer (score 3):

There's a much more simple way with `grep` *one-liner*:

```
grep -rio 'cool' --include=*.txt
```

- `-r` - process recursively
- `-i` - ignore case
- `-o` - print only matched substrings/parts
- `--include=*.txt` - search only files whose name matches `*.txt`

---

The output should contain filename and matched/found part in format:

```
<filename1>.txt:cool
<filename2>.txt:cOol
<filename3>.txt:COOL
...
```

Comment: @αғsнιη, it does print the filename even if there would be *one matched file*. Tested, at least on `grep (GNU grep) 2.25`

Comment: thanks for the grep solution. Grep is probably more efficient than awk, but I am also usingthe RS variable (Record Separator) to get the content for a whole paragraph. There is probably also a solution for regex too, I am not sure. But thanks! Will come handy for sure. :)